# Access to willow garage dataset

Tags: ros, pcl, household-objects-database, rgbd

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am trying to access the datasets at http://pr.willowgarage.com/wiki/Datasets.
Could someone check if the link is available. Because when I try to download for ex the first 08-09-19_10party-100scenes-greenroom/ at
http://pr.willowgarage.com/wiki/Datasets/u/prdata/private/perception/08-09-19_10party-100scenes-greenroom/
I don't see existence of that page.

Any assistance is much appreciated.

Thanks,
Karthik

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55799/access-to-willow-garage-dataset/) by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2831 on 2013-02-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

/u/prdata/... is an internal network folder, not a web address.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2013-02-21**:
Hey so how do I get access to that?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-04-16**:
That's not possible.  There's lots of released datasets.  Where are you getting that url from? It looks like a combination of multiple ones.